# ¿Cómo reportar una edición?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, pregunta-específica

En esta pregunta [La función cin no me la ejecuta correctamente (C++)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499888/la-funci%C3%B3n-cin-no-me-la-ejecuta-correctamente-c) se corrigió el código, básicamente se corrigió el error que era un espacio de más y ahora la pregunta no tiene sentido.

¿Cómo reportar esa edición?

Comment: esa pregunta no debe existir... las preguntas con errores tipográfico/sintaxis se suelen resolver con comentarios ..

Comment: aparte de lo que dijo Arcanis, si crees que una edición es errónea o desmejora la publicación la puedes revertir o reportar la publicación a un moderador y dejar un mensaje claro de lo que pasó, así el moderador revisará el historial de ediciones y hará la acción correspondiente.

Comment: También hay veces que se publican preguntas demasiado sencillas, como por ejemplo como hacer un bucle infinito , que simplemente googleando se resolvería. Creo que habría que eliminar esas preguntas.

Comment: @nadie en ese caso es creo que sería mejor reportarla como pregunta duplicada

Answer (score -1):

El espacio se agregó porque no pudo ponerlo en formato de código.

> El espacio de iostream es intencional, por alguna razón lo pegaba aquí y no me lo reconocía). :

Trata de poner esto mismo en una pregunta, y vas a ver que desaparece.

```
<iostream>
```

Ahora intenta poner con el espacio, no desaparece.

< iostream>

Ahora que está en código no es necesario.

Eso es porque lo toma como HTML.

Para ver el código en texto plano hay que tocar en **Origen**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Source: https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22d6d1c7-df5c-4dca-8630-7918f0400960/view-source

Se ve que hay tres espacios en vez de cuatro, eso hace que no lo tome como código.

El problema que tiene es en QT al escribir en cin, no tiene nada que ver con el `include`.

Comment: Si quitas el espacio de su código funciona correctamente, lo cual es como corregir su código

Comment: @EduardoJiménez En la revisión 1 el espacio no está, el espacio agregado fue solo para que se vea en la pregunta... Además, dice que funciona en onlinegdb, pero no en QT.

Comment: Como ves en la edición 3 (hecha por la autora de la pregunta) incluye el iostream con el espacio

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Sí, pero lo hace para que se vea el `include`.

Comment: por eso es que yo recomiendo usar los 3 backstick **```**... no me confio de formateo de los 4 spacios ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Sí, lo uso también, en mi opinión, debería existir algo que te ponga los backticks automáticamente, o que sugiera agregarlos.

Comment: No sólo es que los añada sino explicar bien cómo usarlos. He editado la mar de preguntas donde la primera línea tenía tres ticks y toda la primera línea.